# Global variable value not updating inside nodejs Promise, resolve & reject both are called

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to get the value of `getMovie()` promise inside a global variable `movie_data`, but the value is not updating outside the promise, it's working fine inside promise but when I try to print the value of `movie_data` inside promise resolver it is still empty. Moreover, resolve & reject both are getting called this is what I am not getting.

---

```
    Output:
     {"_id":"Movie1"} // inside actual promise
     {} // print inside promise resolver
     dummy text to check // print inside promise reject
```

---

```
    Expected Output:
      {"_id":"Movie1"} // inside promise
      {"_id":"Movie1"} // inside promise resolver
```

What is wrong with my code?

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var movie_data = {};
function getMovie(movie_id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    callToMySQLProcedure('GET_FILM_DETAILS', [movie_id], function(err, data) { // call to my stoored procedure and getting response from db
        data.forEach(function(elem) {
            movie_data["_id"] = "Movie1";
            console.log(movie_data);
            resolve(movie_id);
        });
     });
  });
}

getMovie(1)
.then(
    console.log(movie_data),
    console.log('dummy text to check')
)
.catch(function(e) {
   console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: .then expects a **function** as an argument, for a start - so the two console.log's aren't being called "on resolve" and "on reject" - they are called, inline, directly, before the asynchronous part of `getMovie` has even started - see what you did with .catch?

Comment: `.then(result => console.log(result), error =>  console.log('dummy text to check'))`

Comment: You shall not call `resolve` multiple times. Put it after the `forEach` loop.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks it worked :)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the tip, I moved the resolve to bottom of my code.

Comment: @JaromandaX Please write your comment in answer, I will accept and upvote :)

Comment: Would love to see the corrected code.

Comment: @pidloop I honestlty lost that code, but if you can give me your gist I can assist.